# Not getting response when i open an app via mobile but i get response when i open a website on Owasp zap. what could be the issue

Tags: owasp, zap

I tired opening a website i got responses with websites name and more files in it  but when i tried to open an app i get this response and none after that.[this is the response when i open a mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh0VA.png)

i installed the root certificate on pc n lap. connected them using ip n port and ran it and get this response i should do any modification to the app?

i am in the process of learning Owasp zap n penetration testing.

Comment: HAve you looked at https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/can-zap-be-used-to-test-mobile-apps/ ?

Comment: yes i did and followed the same, still unable to run mobile apps

Comment: You could try asking on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users
I dont do mobile testing so cant help any more than that.